# Add child block to register.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I want to include some view files inside my `register.phtml`, like this:

**Register.phml**

```
<div class="account-create">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
.
.
// include another view file here
.
.
</div>
```

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php          
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('foldername/filename.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Comment: the file is getting included now but the code inside the included file is not working. like this the code to display the text box for first name is not working  :<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>